# how to configure and change the default icon for intel xdk app built for android with cordova

Tags: android, cordova, intel-xdk

I have built an html5 mobile application using intel xdk. the problem is that I can not change the app icon when I build with cordova for android "their is no choice like the other build options". I googled about it and found "intelxdk.config.xml" but i did not know where it should be placed. so how to configure my app and where should I place the configuration file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must specify the icon's location and name within the intelxdk.config.xml file. Please see these links for more details:

- https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/xdkdocs#477358
- https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/articles/using-the-cordova-for-android-ios-etc-build-option
- https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/articles/cordova-for-android-build-options
- https://github.com/gomobile/intelxdk-config-xml-for-cordova-builds

The icon images need to be located within your project directory, currently they must be located within the "source directory" (see the main project page for a definition of that, usually defaults to www). You specify the directory within the intelxdk.config.xml file relative to the "source directory."

Comment: after upgrade intelxdk to the latest version I found a GUI of the build options on the Projects tab. including icons and splash screen